Sort %b-%y in x-axis in ggplot2
The x-axis supposed arrange the date in ascending order, such as "Nov-23", "Feb-24", then "Apr-24". How can I handle this situation in R? I have tried to use as.POSIXct() , or as.Date() but the error still exist...
Reproducible Example :
data <- data.frame(
      d = c("Apr-24", "Feb-24", "Nov-23"),
      duration = 1:3
    )
    

My Code :
    data |>
      ggplot(aes(x = d, y = duration)) +
      geom_point() +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))


*Add on, the original data supposed to be this ...
data<-tribble(
~date,~duration,
"2023-11-01",6.96,
"2023-11-01",6.71,
"2023-11-01",5.61,
"2023-11-01",3.47,
"2023-11-01",-0.613,
"2023-11-02",3.60,
"2023-12-01",3.95,
"2023-12-01",4.87,
"2023-12-01",0.541,
"2023-12-01",1.88,
"2023-12-01",-0.0250,
"2024-01-01",6.68,
"2024-01-01",4.85,
"2024-01-01",5.13,
"2024-01-01",1.58,
"2024-01-01",2.00,
"2024-02-01",6.63,
"2024-02-01",4.43,
"2024-02-01",5.65,
"2024-02-01",4.54,
"2024-02-01",-0.0353,
"2024-02-16",1.54,
"2024-03-01",6.94,
"2024-03-01",6.03,
"2024-03-01",4.56,
"2024-03-01",3.54,
"2024-03-01",1.83,
"2024-04-01",12.8,
"2024-04-01",7.05,
"2024-04-01",-2.95,
"2024-04-01",6.68,
"2024-04-01",-0.0224,
"2024-05-01",6.86,
"2024-05-01",4.75,
"2024-05-01",1.47,
"2024-05-01",5.92,
"2024-05-01",0.653,
"2024-06-01",-6.21,
"2024-06-01",-6.21,
"2024-06-01",-6.21)
Thank you :D

I see two options, one is to convert Year-Mon to a date, the other is to use the {zoo} package which has support for a yearmon object.
library (ggplot2)
data$date <- as.Date(paste0("01-",data$d), format = "%d-%b-%y")
data |>
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = duration)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%y", date_breaks = "1 month")

library (zoo)
data$ym <- as.yearmon(data$d, "%b-%y")
data |>
  ggplot(aes(x = ym, y = duration)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  scale_x_yearmon(format = "%b-%y") 


Thank you very much @Michiel.
After several hours of trying, I think I managed to do it (after your guidance.)
Actually, the date is in "%Y-%m-%d" format initially. Just I create a new column name "d" which format of '%b-%y' and do the work. I think that's not efficient.
Also, when using zoo package, I realize some of the date in x-axis disappear, that's weird. Anyway thank you!

Hey @Michiel, I have updated the full original reproducible data on my post anyway. :D

It is not clear whether you want a "timeline" or the dates ordered as discrete steps.
@Michiel gave a great answer for sorting your example on a timeline.
Assuming you want to work with "discrete" ordering of your dates and not a timeline, you will have to control the "order" of your x-axis breaks.
{ggplot} uses an alphabetical order. That is the reason why Apr-24 (interpreted as a string starting with A comes first).
One way of "encoding" a discrete ordering is the use of factor(). Think about a vector which allows you to control a.) the sequence/order and b.) the actual label.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# as above this is to convert the strings into a date to use the "natural [time] ordering" 
data$date <- as.Date(paste0("01-",data$d), format = "%d-%b-%y")

# now let's order the dates and coerce the date column into a factor
data <- data |> 
    dplyr::arrange(date) |> 
    dplyr::mutate(date = factor(
                      date            # our vector of date values
                    , levels = date   # the ordering we established 
                    , labels = d      # the way we want to see it printed
                    ) 
    )

# lets plot it
data |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = duration)) + 
    geom_point()

This yields


Thank you very much @Ray.
I did take yours and steps as learning.
Actually, the date is in "%Y-%m-%d" format. Just I create a new column name "d" which format of '%b-%y' and do the work. I think that's not efficient.
After see both of your approach, I decided to not to create a column "d" anymore. Thank you!

Hey @Ray, I have updated the full original reproducible data on my post, just in case it might works differently... :)

@Gambit it is still not clear whether you want to have a "timeline" or present the measurements at different dates in a "discrete" manner.
Moreover, check how {ggplot2} handles the different formats. Then you will get there. It might also answer why certain things "disappear".
When you read in your data, you get
data
# A tibble: 40 × 2
   date       duration
   <chr>         <dbl>
 1 2023-11-01    6.96     # first day (as string) in your data, think x = 1
 2 2023-11-01    6.71 
 3 2023-11-01    5.61 
 4 2023-11-01    3.47 
 5 2023-11-01   -0.613
 6 2023-11-02    3.6       # "next" day ~ think x = 2
 7 2023-12-01    3.95      # "next-next" day ~ think x = 3
 8 2023-12-01    4.87 
 9 2023-12-01    0.541
10 2023-12-01    1.88 

If you inspect this dataframe/tibble, you can see that your first column is interpreted as "character" (i.e. <chr>).
This means, ggplot will order your date values in alpha-lexographical order.
Note: the actual value (on your x-axis) has not temporal relationship. {ggplot2} just checks for the sequence in terms of 2023-11-02 comes after 2023-11-01, and the latter before 2023-12-01. The x-axis steps just mark the "next" alpha-lexographical entry (discrete value).
The plot you generate shows this "discrete" (step-by-step) relationship. X-axis ticks represent the "next" discrete candidate (day).
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = date, y = duration)) + 
    geom_point()


If you coerce the date into a date-format, {ggplot2} will order it in a temporal order. In particular, the x-axis distance between 2023-11-01 and 2023-12-01 has a "meaning". It is interpreted as a (continual) month, i.e. along the month there are other data points (aka days of the month) possible.
Note: there are many ways to coerce a string into a date format.
I use {lubridate} here for simplicity, as it has an intuitive ymd() function to coerce character strings.
data |> 
    mutate(
        date_as_date = lubridate::ymd(date)  # just to make clear we have a date now
    ) 

# A tibble: 40 × 3
   date       duration date_as_date
   <chr>         <dbl> <date>      
 1 2023-11-01    6.96  2023-11-01  
 2 2023-11-01    6.71  2023-11-01  
 3 2023-11-01    5.61  2023-11-01  
 4 2023-11-01    3.47  2023-11-01  

If you plot this
data |> 
    mutate(date_as_date = lubridate::ymd(date)) |> 
    #--------- plot it now ---------------------------------
    ggplot(aes(x = date_as_date, y = duration)) + 
      geom_point()


Things to point out

you might spot the slightly off-set value for 2023-11-02. The 2nd Nov is place proportional to the dates in the months in the axis (~ very close to the 1st or month and far away from next start of month). Change this to 2023-11-15 to make this more prominent. Or check what happens in February 2024 where you have a data point in the middle of the month.
ggplot now offers a "reasonable" x-axis scale (and labelling). This depends a bit on the dimension of your graph/device, etc. In my case it stripped off the dates and works with a sort of quarterly scale.

There is now many ways to "beautify" your x-axis. What I get from your comments is that you prefer a month-year label.
data |> 
    mutate(date_as_date = lubridate::ymd(date)) |> 
    
    #--------- plot it now ---------------------------------
    ggplot(aes(x = date_as_date, y = duration)) + 
        geom_point() + 
    
    #--------- beautify x-axis labels ----------------------
        scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b %Y")


Using month-year/year-month might work with this scale/plot dimension.
If you have a longer time series, you may have to be a bit more sparse on the labels.
Try to understand

variable type/format
how ggplot uses these formats and orders them
how you define your labels
apply the function to scale to your liking or go for an approach where you define the labels in your dataframe/outside vector and use this column/outside vector to "label".

Enjoy tinkering with ggplot!
